# How Do I Schedule Events in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, scheduled-tasks, customtkinter

I want to create a code using tkinter that prints a black screen, prints a logo, then prints the black screen again. I am trying to use after() but I just get the black screen, it loads for a while, then goes to a grey screen.

```
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter as ctk
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
root = ctk.CTk()
root.title("FreeBank")
root.geometry(f"{screenWidth}x{screenHeight}")


def initialScreenSettings(root):
    root.config(bg="black")
    root.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
    print('main')



def loadingScreen(root):
    print('loading screen start')
    canvas = Canvas(root, width = screenWidth, height = screenHeight)
    canvas.pack() 
    img = PhotoImage(file="FreeBank_Logo.png")
    canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)
    print('loading screen end')

initialScreenSettings(root)
root.after(5000, loadingScreen(root))
root.after(10000, initialScreenSettings(root))

root.mainloop()
```

here is my code.

I have tried adding root.mainloop into the function loadingScreen:

```
def loadingScreen(root):
    print('loading screen start')
    canvas = Canvas(root, width = screenWidth, height = screenHeight)
    canvas.pack() 
    img = PhotoImage(file="FreeBank_Logo.png")
    canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)
    print('loading screen end')
    root.mainloop()
```

That just prints the logo immediately and nothing else.
I know for a fact that the code does run through loadingScreen as I have added print() statements to test and they show up.

Comment: Note that `root.after(5000, loadingScreen(root))` will execute `loadingScreen(root)` immediately, not after 5000ms.  It should be `root.after(5000, loadingScreen, root)` instead.  Same for another `root.after(10000, ...)`. Actually the second `root.after(10000,...)` is useless because the canvas covers  all the space of the window.